# Clausius-Clapeyron relation for high pressures

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas, atmospheric-science, condensation

I can see that the [Clausius-Clapeyron relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Clapeyron_relation) depends on the change in specific volume $\Delta v = v_g (1 - \frac{v_c}{v_g}) = v_g - v_c$, with $v_c$ equal to the volume of the condensed phase and $v_g$ equal to the volume of the gas phase. One approximation is to replace $v_g = \frac{RT}{P}$ and $\frac{v_c}{v_g} = 0$ when $v_g >> v_c$. This only works for low pressures and temperatures (much lower than critical pressure and temperature).

For high pressures/temperatures how can I calculate $\Delta v$ (and so $v_c$, and $v_g$)?

Comment: You need an equation of state or tabulated values. In the standard approximation we use ideal gas law for the vapor and neglect the liquid. You can use virial, for example, for the vapor and some other estimate (Rackett?) for the liquid. Or, use the van der Waals equation or some other equation of state to calculate $v_g$ and $v_c$.

Comment: @Themis I would like not to use tabulated values as I think it should be possible to derive a more complex approximation that works for higher temp? When using standard approximation and a slightly different latent heat (6% higher than triple point latent heat) I can get very close results for CO2/Methane. For water vapour however the closest results are when linearly decreasing latent heat up to 8% at the critical point. With van der waals it is not clear to me how to get to an analytical form where pressure and temperature terms are separated (like f(P)dp = g(T)dt). Would you know?

Comment: YOu can use the vdW equation, or any other cubic equation of state to calculate (1) the saturation pressure, (2) heat of vaporization and (3) volumes of vapor and liquid (among other things). It is a somewhat involved calculation but it is explained in may undergraduate textbooks on chemical engineering thermodynamics. Keep in mind these equations are not as good for polar molecules like water. Two references are https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/fundamentals-of-chemical/9780132693158/ and https://bcs.wiley.com/he-bcs/Books?action=index&itemId=0471661740&bcsId=2932

Comment: @Themis thank you for the references. I believe I have looked through equivalent references and haven't found a satisfactory answer for the liquid/gas equilibrium line in p,T space that one can get with clausius-clapeyron (only in p,v space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a cubic equation such as the van der Waals equation,
$$P = \frac{RT}{v-b}-\frac{a}{v^2}$$

to calculate the properties of a fluid according to the procedure below.

1. Solve the van der Waals equation for $v_l$ and $v_v$ at temperature $T$ and pressure $P^\text{sat}(T)$. The equation has three real solutions, the smallest is $v_l$, the largest is $v_v$ and the middle root is discarded.
2. Calculate the heat of vaporization as follows:
   $$\Delta h_\text{vap} = h^R(v_v)-h^R(v_l)$$
   with
   $$
      h^R(v) = Pv - RT - \frac{a}{v}
   $$
   where $a$ is the parameter in the van der Waals equation.

**Comments**

- The van der Waals is not accurate enough for engineering calculations. Instead we use the Soave-Redlich-Kwong (SRK) or the Peng-Robinson (PR) equations, both of which are modifications of the van der Waals but a bit more complicated in algebra. Even these are more appropriate for small non polar molecules. Nonetheless, the van der Waals ought to give a better aproximation than the Clausius-Clapeyron.
- The procedure described here assumes that we know the saturation pressure at any temperature. If we don't, we can get it from the van der Waals equation, but this involves another layer of iterations. I'll be happy to explain if that might be useful.

Comment: This is indeed going in the right direction, and I am particularly interested in the latter point i.e. calculating the saturation pressure as a function of only temperature (plus latent heat and cubic equation of state's parameters that you already covered)

Comment: I will update my answer to include the calculation of Psat -- but I'll need some time for that.